# How toBulk Delete Projects in Jira Data Center?

Tags: groovy, jira, jira-rest-api

Can somebody assist me with the Groovy script for deleting numerous projects at once? We are already using scriptrunner. Although I know how to delete a single project using the REST API, I can only delete several projects by making multiple calls.

I'm looking for a groovy script that deletes projects with the same permission schemes. I already looked at [BULK DELETING POJECTS](https://shaakunthala.wordpress.com/2016/03/27/jira-bulk-delete-issues-using-groovy/) but this does not help; it's giving an error when running in the script console.

Comment: Please provide the code that you are using (no link to external website). And the exact error would be of interest too, to be of help.